# How can I get to the coffin inside the giant pumpkin?

Tags: costume-quest

I've recently gotten past the first section of the Autumn Haven Mall, reaching the area which contains shops that you can trick-or-treat (as opposed to the initial "under construction" section).

In that very area, the one containing the bobbing for apples mini-game and the costume contest, there is a giant pumpkin with a coffin in its mouth located at the lower left corner (I'd take a screenshot if I could).

How am I supposed to reach that coffin? Do I need to make use of a costume I still do not have access to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to drop down from a higher level into it, if we're talking about the same giant pumpkin with a coffin in it.  Check out this video at about 1:40 in:

Comment: If you can't get upstairs yet, you might have to advance the plot.  I seem to remember there being a kid that blocks access to certain parts of the upper level until you've cleared a particular part of the mall level.